Realistic probability density function (pdf) for Radar measurement noise
Edit 1: A few tangential questions are posed in this question to get community help
Radar: FMCW | Measurements: Bearing angle, range, and range rate | Application: Aircraft/ship surveillance
Example methods: Angle from multiple receive antennas, range and range rate from digital IQ signal phase measurement.
Measurement noise distribution/s: ?
In a radar detection problem that measures bearing angle, range, range rate using FMCW radar, the quadrature components I and Q are in practice, are normally distributed. However, it is well-studied that the magnitude of IQ signals is Rayleigh distributed Question. Now, addressing the sensor measurements, what is a realistic noise distribution? Phase from IQ signals give the range and range rate information.

If the use of computing magnitude is obtaining the signal strength, does this influence the noise in bearing (angle) measurements or (may be) range measurements? Is there a study to identify the noise PDFs in various measurements? In SAR images, magnitude is the image intensity - making way for Rayleigh distribution.

[Slightly tangential question] Also, what is the use of envelope detection for RADARs? Am I incorrect in assuming that it is not applicable for FMCW measurements.


What I have been searching for: realistic PDF of radar measurements (range, elevation, bearing angle to target) for maximum likelihood estimation.
Few examples I came across are:

In SAR, noise is modeled as Rayleigh distributed: Paper.
Non-Gaussian (mixture of Gaussian + Laplacian) or mixture of Gaussians for heavy-tailed distribution of radar measurement noise. Paper.
Symmetric alpha stable distribution for bearing measurements from Radar. Paper - Cauchy is more robust than Gaussian assumption.

Thank you!

In Kalman filter, radar measurements include bearing angle and range; the measurement prediction step involves transformation from the Cartesian state information to the polar coordinates - making it a Ricean distribution. Source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/359447061_The_Probability_Density_Function_of_Bearing_Obtained_From_a_Cartesian-to-Polar_Transformation

When you ask about "sensor measurements", what do you mean, exactly?

@MarcusMüller I'm referring to the digital measurements from the radar sensor and their distribution. For navigation application quoted here, bearing angles and range. I'm also looking one step prior: IQ signals that result in phase and amplitude of the received signals. Noises in I and Q samples are Gaussian but the magnitude is Rayleigh. To get to the end measurements for navigation filters, if I assume the sensor package gives bearing and range, I want to understand their distribution.

OK, but then you need to define what kind of radar sensor you are talking about, and the radar algorithms it uses – different kinds of radars and different kinds of methods yield fundamentally different error distributions.

@MarcusMüller edited the question to add details as suggested. Thank you!

From what I've seen, Gamma and Rician distributions are pretty common nowadays. I think Gamma is becoming more popular since Rician distributions are necessarily symmetric where as gamma distributions may be asymmetric.

@Baddioes could you point me to some references please? FMCW radar measurement pdfs and if possible, corresponding data processing practices.
